# Ajax FileUpload, los archivos se quedan en espera siempre

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Declaración de Ajax FileUpload en Archivo Aspx:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload runat="server" ID="fluAsistencias" MaximumNumberOfFiles="12" OnUploadComplete="fluAsistencias_UploadComplete" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png" />
```

Declaración de Evento UploadComplete en Archivo Aspx.cs:

```
protected void fluAsistencias_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
    string serverPath = "";

    serverPath = Server.MapPath("~/Archivos/Clientes/VIRUTEX/Imagenes/Asistencia");

    if (!Directory.Exists(serverPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(serverPath);
    }

    fluAsistencias.SaveAs(serverPath + fileName);
}
```

Declaración de Handlers en archivo web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>

<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
      <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
    </httpHandlers>
 </system.web>
```

El Problema es el siguiente, tengo todo el código anterior en mi sitio ASP.net, el problema es que no se esta disparando el evento UploadComplete, ya que las imágenes que se cargan en el control no pasan de la leyenda que dice "Pendientes", anexo imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya eh probado quitando los cada uno de los handlers haber si tenia uno de mas y sigue sin funcionar.

Ya me fije que las librerías estén bien cargadas y actualizadas para este control.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: En el page_load de la pagina intenta los siguiente:

fluAsistencias.OnUploadComplete += fluAsistencias_UploadComplete
if (Page.IsPosback)
{
 ....
}

Comment: Aunque no me dejo poner el On, la linea quedo así:  fluAsistencias.UploadComplete += fluAsistencias_UploadComplete;

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {...} pero no funciona, sigue igual.

Comment: Trata de ver en modo desarrollador en chrome que error te da en consola. Eso podría dar algunas pistas de que es lo que pasa.

Comment: Trata de chequear esta pagina. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/ajax-control-toolkit-tutorial-ajaxfileupload-part-three/

Comment: Gracias, lo tomare en cuenta!